# Visual Studio 2013 programming "<<" is not matching operands?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, loops, for-loop, void

I am getting an error saying the operand "<<" (right before times3(x) in the main function ) does not match the operand types being outputted in that line. What am I doing wrong? I searched for errors similar to it and found that its an inclusion error but i thought having  would fix it. Also, countdown(seconds) in the main function is not being recognized and giving me an error. Why is that? The problems keep occurring when working with void.

'

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <limits>
   using namespace std;

   bool die(const string & msg);
   double triple(double x);
   double times9(double x);
   void triple(double & result, double x);
   void times3(double & x);
   void countdown(unsigned seconds);
   bool restore();


   int main(){
       double x;
       cout << "x: " << endl;
       cin >> x;
       cout << "The triple of " << x << " is " << triple(x) << endl;
       cout << "9 times of " << x << " is " << times9(x) << endl;
       cout << "3 times of " << x << " is " << times3(x) << endl;
       unsigned seconds;
       cout << "seconds: " << endl;
       cin >> seconds;
       cout << countdown(seconds) << endl;
   }

   bool die(const string & msg){
       cout << "Fatal error: " << msg << endl;
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   double triple(double x){
       return 3 * x;
   }
   double times9(double x){
    return 3 * triple(x);
   }

   void triple(double & result, double x){
       x = 3 * x;
   }

   void times3(double & x){
       x = triple(x);
   }

   void countdown(unsigned & seconds){
       unsigned count = seconds;
       cin >> seconds || die("input failure");
       for (unsigned i = seconds; i <= size; i--){
           cout << i << endl;
       }
       cout << "Blast off! " << endl;
   }

   bool resotre(){
       cin.clear();
       cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
       return cin.good();
   }'
```

Comment: As well as all the other problems, the `triple` function does not write anything to `result`

Comment: You could be much better off having your functions take argument by value, and return the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in earlier answer, you need to change the return type of your function from void to the data type of variable your trying to print.

Another issue in your code is with function `void countdown(unsigned & seconds)`
Declaration and definition of the functions are different.
You have declared it as `void countdown(unsigned seconds);` but at the time of defining it you are using `void countdown(unsigned & seconds)`. In declaration you are declaring it to take arguments `by value` but in definition you are making it to take arguments `by reference.`

Also in the `for loop` of the function `countdown` you have written

`for (unsigned i = seconds; i <= 0; i--)`, this won't print any output, since your condition is `i<=0`, i think you tried to type `i >= 0`. :)

Comment: I made the above changes and it finally recognized it! Thank you! But now the issue is instead of outputting the countdown as I have it in the loop, it outputs a random set of numbers and letters such as 01012Ab. What is causing that problem?

Answer (score 1):

`times3` returns `void`. Try:

```
times3(x);
cout << "3 times of " << x << " is " << x << endl;
```

Or have `times3()` return double instead of passing by reference.

```
double times3(double x);
```

Comment: Ohhh ok I did it and it worked except if I run the program inputting one, the output comes out to be 001AF, when clearly 3 times 1 is 3. Is that simply an error in my code?

Comment: Also why is it that countdown(seconds) is not outputting what I have in void when I run the program?

Comment: You're going to need to store the old and new values of `x` for this to work